# Replace vowel with next does not work

Tags: java, replace

I have a string input and want to **replace every vowel** in that string with its next vowel.

However, it does not seem to work correct. I have tried various input like:

```
venky -> vinky // Correct
ui    -> uo    // Incorrect, expected ao
ai    -> ao    // Incorrect, expected eo
```

The vowel order is

```
char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

My code is:

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str, res;
        char ch;
        int i, j;
        char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        str = r.nextLine();
        res = str;

        for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            ch = str.charAt(i);

            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (ch == 'u') {
                    res = str.replace(ch, 'a');
                    break;
                } else if (ch == vowels[j]) {
                    res = str.replace(ch, vowels[j+1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("String after replacing the vowels with next vowel : "
            + res);
    }   
}
```

Comment: *"`ui -> uo` and `ai -> ao`"* - What is expected, `ui -> ao`, `ai -> eo`?

Comment: Why dont you do something like [this](https://hastebin.com/yutojihoco.cpp) and run it for every character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
res = str.replace(ch, vowels[j+1]);
```

Consider the input ai. The 1st time you pass here you change the value of res to ei, the second time you replace the i in the initial string ai, not in the modified one. So res gets the new value ao.

Anyway, even if you fix this particular case you may hit some other issue with longs words containing many wovels as you replace the first occurence (imagine the case of ae you would get ie). You should build the result one char at a time, with either the unmodified letter or the next wovel.

Comment: Thank you I updated my code to res = res.replace(ch, vowels[j+1]); and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the vowel in your `str` variable and saving it to `res` then you break and continue on your `str` which has the previous vowel not replaced.

You would need put your response together char by char

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `String.replace` will replace all occurrence of a char in your String.

Since you traverse over your String, one original character might be replaced multiple times, for example:

```
acac -> ecec -> ecic
```

You will receive `ecic` instead of `ecec`.

So I think you can create another String based on the current Strin to avoid the sideeffect of `String.replace`:

```
char[] output = new char[str.length()];
for(i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    ch = str.charAt(i);

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if (ch == 'u') {
            output[i] = 'a';
        } else if(ch == vowels[j]) {
            output[i] = vowels[j+1];
        } else {
            output[i] = ch;
        }
    }
}

String res = new String(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = str.replace(ch, vowels[j+1]);
```

will replace the string value and put in `res` variable but on the next time it will not use the old res variable for further modification thats why it is giving wrong answer try changing.

```
str = str.replace(ch, 'a');
str = str.replace(ch, vowels[j+1]);
```

and print `str` instead of `len`